# Java code quality in methods calling methods

Tags: java, object-oriented, code-quality

I am currently working with an "interesting" code-base and see the following type of thing alot in the code.

```
public Object doSomething()
{
    Object obj = new Object();

    // Do some stuff to the object

    obj = doSomthingElse(obj);    

    return obj;
}
```

I always feel when looking at this kind of code that it is somewhat incorrect to have an object be passed into a method as a parameter but also set the object returned by the method to the same variable that was referencing the passed object. I would usually do something like the following, where I create a new variable to avoid any confusion.

```
public Object doSomething()
{
    Object obj = new Object();

    // Do some stuff to the object

    Object anotherObj = doSomthingElse(obj);     

    return anotherObj;
}
```

Am I wrong in thinking the second code snippet is more readable/correct?

Comment: Do you use `Object` to mean that different methods handle different classes but display the same pattern, or does your code base use the actual `Object` class a lot?

Comment: I can't see that this could have any answer than just one opinion against another. The above code would not attract my attention either way.

Comment: The former code has an implication to me that "obj" is an object (probably immutable) for which a replacement (probably a copy with some details changed) is being returned.  The latter code implies that the returned object is not closely related to the one passed in (although appropriate variable naming could change my feelings about that).

Comment: Would you feel differently if the variable was a primitive value instead of an object reference?  For example, if your function had a local variable, `double d;` and it assigned `d = f(d, ...)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Answer (score 3):

If the method call is transforming the object without creating a copy of it (and then returning the same object, with the changes), the statement `obj = doSomthingElse(obj);` has no effect (you could just perform `doSomthingElse(obj);` instead).

If the method creates and returns another object (that is a modified copy of the original), then what the statement `obj = doSomthingElse(obj);` does is called **variable reuse**. To say that it is a good or a bad practice would be nothing more than an opinion.

Sticking to your abstract example, my opinion would be that you need to add some comments to the code explaining what the `obj` variable represents. Then, reusing it or not, you should try to stick to what is documented (the variable's role in the code).

If the result of `doSomthingElse(obj)` is another object and represents something different from the documented role of the variable `obj`, then you should use another variable (as you did), IMHO.

Comment: If you need to add comments to explain the "obj" variable, you should _give it a better name to begin with_

Comment: Yes. Trying to make the code self-explanatory should be the first option. It's what I think nowadays (the question is more than 3 years old :)).

Answer (score 1):

There's no right or wrong answer to this.  It's very subjective. I would say that the style you are leaning towards is widely considered valid but maybe a little picky to some.

If you don't want to reuse variables, I would strongly recommend declaring them `final`.  This will make your intention clear to the compiler as well as other devs.

I would avoid declaring a variable simply to return it but that's probably just there to illustrate your scenario.

Comment: Agree that Declaring  avariable just to return  is debateable.  However, it aids in debugging, and is a good place to explain what is happening  bygiving it  agood variable name.  Of course, the function name should also be explanatory too.

Answer (score 1):

Variable reuse isn't horribly wrong, but you miss a chance at writing clearer code by **giving variables good names**.  For example, if you were manipulating a Point, use

```
Point origin = new Point();
Point translated = doSomething(origin);
return translated;
```