# Should I use functions based on Applicatives or Monads?

Tags: coding-style, haskell

There are a lot of functions that accomplish the same thing, but using `Applicative` vs `Monad` definitions.

Some examples are:

- `(<*>)` vs `ap`
- `pure` vs `return`
- `(*>)` vs `(>>)`
- `traverse` vs `mapM`
- `sequenceA` vs `sequence`
- `liftA` vs `liftM`
- `liftA2` vs `liftM2`
- etc.

And for `Alternative` vs `MonadPlus`:

- `empty` vs `mzero`
- `(<|>)` vs `mplus`

In the scenario that prompted this question, I wanted to `traverse`/`mapM` where the `Applicative`/`Monad` is `[]`.

In general, when it is known that the result will be the same, is it better style to use the `Applicative` ones or the `Monad` ones?  E.g., is one more readable than another, or maybe faster than the other?

Edit (in response being suggested as a duplicate): Personally, I find these to be equally readable.  I am in no way asking about maintainability, as these can be used interchangeably, and preferring one over another would have no impact on the code structure.  I'm really wondering if one is more *idiomatic*, or more *efficient*, than the other.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: The general rule of thumb I follow – although I don't have a good source for this, which is why this isn't an answer – is "always use the `Applicative` ones".  In a hypothetically correctly-having-`Applicative`-from-the-beginning Haskell, we'd *only* have `(<*>)`, `traverse`, etc.  (Also: `liftA` is the same as `fmap` / `(<$>)`, which is the real thing to use there.)

Comment: @gnat I'm curious, why do you think this question is a duplicate?  To me, it doesn't seem to be even be superficially related to the "duplicate" you identified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For both efficiency and generality, you should typically prefer the most general operators. So you should use `Applicative` operators in preference to `Monad`, and `Alternative` to `MonadPlus`.

The efficiency difference is often not significant, so if you already have a `Monad`/`MonadPlus` constraint, you should feel free to use any of the relevant operators to produce the nicest looking code.

The [`ApplicativeDo`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo) extension can allow you to get the benefit of `do`-notation without a `Monad` requirement.  I recommend the [Haxl paper](http://community.haskell.org/~simonmar/papers/haxl-icfp14.pdf) for an non-trivial example where there is a quite significant performance difference between `Applicative` and `Monad` (and was a motivator for implementing `ApplicativeDo` notation).

Comment: I agree with this answer, except that often, using the most general operator gives *less* efficiency, because the particular type may have special properties that make the algorithm faster for it (trivial example: built-in `[a]` versus length-tagged `([a], Int)` have, respectively, `O(n)` and `O(1)` length functions).

Comment: I'm not suggesting using the most general operator in all cases; I'm only suggesting it in the context of choosing between operations in the `Monad`, `Applicative`, `Functor` hierarchy and closely related classes. The idea is not to pay for something you don't use. In the general case, a less contrived example is `nub` versus `nubOrd`. For more elaborate functions built from the `Monad`/`Applicative` operations, the extra structure can allow for better algorithms, e.g. a generate-and-test algorithm where you filter as you go, but the implementation difference is more than swapping operators.