# If-statement, organize by conditional or effect

Tags: coding-style, if-statement

A co-worker submitted code for a PR the other day, which effectively follows this flow:

```
if (a)
  do something_a
else if (b)
  do something_b
else if (c)
  do something_a
```

where `a`, `b`, and `c` are mutually exclusive conditions (in reality, they are all checking if a variable is equal to different values).

In my experience however, I've always tried to collapse the conditionals that have the same results with ORs, like the following.

```
if (a OR c)
  do something_a
else if (b)
  do something_b
```

**Disregarding performance**, which version is better? Which version is easier to maintain in the future?

Comment: "they are all checking if a variable is equal to different values" - is this in a language which has a `switch` type construct?

Comment: it is, but a, b, and c are methods which effectively do the check, otherwise yes, a switch-case would be a nice alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

At least as the question was originally asked, the two aren't equivalent.

In the first, `something_a` is executed only if `a` is true or if `b` is false *and* `c` is true. I.e., `if (a || (c && !b))`.

In the second, `something_a` is performed if either `a` or `c` is true (regardless of `b`). Only if those are both false do we consider `b`.

As such, your first question shouldn't be which is easier to maintain, but which behavior you actually want.

If the conditions are exclusive, so that difference doesn't arise, then I'd consider the relationship between the conditions, if any. If it's basically coincidence that two inputs happen to produce the same output, then I'd probably list each individual, since it's probably easier to simply map from inputs to results when each is listed directly. The second becomes interesting primarily when/if there's a fairly obvious relationship between the conditions.

For example, if you had something like:

```
if (customer has no ID || customer's age < minimum)
    reject order for alcoholic beverage
```

In this case, we have two different manifestations of what's really a single condition: the customer can't prove they're old enough to buy the drink. They're not (from our perspective) two unrelated conditions that happen to lead to the same result--rather, they're just different ways of expressing the same condition, so it makes more sense to group them together.

Comment: The question has now been clarified to make it explicit that a, b and c are mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Duplication is bad, therefore your first version is inferior.

How much worse it is depends on how much stuff `do_stuff_a()` actually is; if it's really just one line, then it's no big deal, but repeated groups of statements should generally be combined or refactored into a method.

Answer (score -1):

Neither is 'better' its just coding style.

(Disregarding both performance and whether they have the same result!!!!!)

Comment: The first one violates DRY, so they are not equivalent.

Comment: not if its just a function call

Comment: Coding style is not just "just" coding style. Different styles have different semantics.

Comment: no. they literally have the same semantics