# Does this anti-pattern have a name?

Tags: anti-patterns

Here is a piece of cool code to add the two integers, a and b:

```
NameService nameService = NameService.getSingletonInstance();
OperationService operationService = nameService.resolve(OperationService.class);
ValueFactory factory = OperationServiceFactory.newInstance();
AbstractValue va = factory.newIntegerValue(a);
AbstractValue vb = factory.newIntegerValue(b);
Operator operator = operationService.resolve(AdditonService.class);
AbstractValue vc = operator.performOperation(a, b);
int c = nameService.resolve(IntegerDecorator.class).getValue(vc);
```

Unfortunately I cannot paste the actual production code that does a little bit more (while not much) but the problem should be obvious: there is much more code than minimally required and despite of "design patterns applied" it is very difficult to read or refactor it. It can be written much simpler and shorter but the author of the code claims you being unprofessional for saying so. Where is the problem with the code? It really could not be that there is no any.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Naming considered harmful](https://the-whiteboard.github.io/2017/11/21/naming-considered-harmful.html): *STOP IT. Avoid naming things that don’t need to have names. This was bad code. We gave it a name and joked about it. But now, I’ve got a name for it. It is not a good thing. This code already had a name before we christened it – it is Bad Code. __Use names for things that you want to remember__.*

Comment: Call it [The Daily WTF](https://thedailywtf.com/), if you like.

Comment: ... or simply [Overengineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overengineering), if you prefer that.

Comment: Have the author of the code read [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/141005/64132)

Comment: `getSingletonInstance`. There’s your first anti-pattern right there. It’s called the singleton anti-pattern.

Comment: Good grief! This example should go into a museum of horrors, alongside pickled body parts.

Comment: This is a [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/) if I ever saw one.

Comment: Trying to coin a name for it, I'll pick "embroidering".

Comment: @amon: You'll want to remember bad things too, so you can stay away from them. I wouldn't fly a plane into the Bermuda triangle. If I had never heard of it before, I wouldn't be too fussed about flying into it (and presumably regret it later). As long as the name is attributed to the _entire range of possibilities for the same mistake_, and not just a particular subset of it; naming it seems fine (e.g. the northern half of the Bermuda triangle doesn't need a unique name to warn pilots flying into it). "Bad code" is an overly terse summary, and not enough to identify the problem ahead of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could call this [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) where the programmer uses patterns without fully understanding why.  Before you go accusing someone of this, make sure you understand the reasons behind these patterns yourself.

This isn't the actual production code, you said so yourself.  Therefore you have to seriously consider the possibility that this might be even necessary under the circumstances.  Even the code you wrote might actually be feasible in the right circumstances, such as in a code parser where operators and operands are all potentially dynamic.

Perhaps the author of this code merely meant to be as flexible as possible.  It is questionable whether or not the added flexibility is worth the lack of readability.