# How to build your class in a readable way

Tags: coding-style, code-quality, clean-code

When developping a project I follow the OOP principles and break my code into classes and most of the time I go for one file = one class.

Now I dont know how to organize my code into the class and even into my own functions/methods I'm still looking for ways to improve the readability.

I think the general consensus is :

1. attributes
2. Constructors
3. Getters/Setters
4. Methods

But once I get to the method part I dont know if I should organize by public/protected/private members, or if I should put related methods together ?

IE :

Methods for database operation, then methods for user input validation, then methods for event handling.

What If I put some code in a method, and then I call this method in a lots of my others class method ?

```
public void f1(){
    mymethod();
    // other stuff
}

public void f2(){
    mymethod();
    // other stuff
}
```

Where do I put 'mymethod' definition for an optimal readibility ?
Should I declare it before f1 and f2 or after both ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: With modern development IDE's, the order hardly matters. People will use the dropdowns or F12 to find a method.  The practice our team uses is to define the properties and methods in alphabetical order, which prevents any merge issues that could result from code moving around.

Comment: Every shop will have their own tradition but there is literature regarding  this issue: [Uncle Bobs Stepdown Rule](https://grysz.com/2015/11/13/reformat-java-code-in-intellij-according-to-uncle-bobs-stepdown-rule/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quit procrastinating. Don't waste your time with this stuff.

Modern tools facilitate jumping around to parts of the code so effectively you could order a classes functions and properties almost completely randomly and most folks wouldn't even notice.

There are tools that can do it for you if it's really that important to you. Find a decent tool that works with your development language and just use one of the defaults. Done.

Comment: Hundred times this. Order of stuff within class is mostly irrelevant when using modern IDE. The readability and understandability are in different areas.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking this for your own, personal projects, then @whatsisname nailed it. If you're joining a team, take a look at some of the existing code, and use their style.

Comment: Agreed! Consistency is valuable when working on a team.  I'm not opposed to adopting an opinionated styleguide. For example, AirBnB's JavaScript styleguide [specifies a very specific structure](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react#ordering) for React component classes.

Answer (score 0):

re: public/protected/private

A good argument is to put the **public** methods first, cause *they are the API of your class* and therefore "more important".  Let users see them first, to get a feel for what the class can do for them.  For example, if they think they want to use this class to talk to a database, they'd expect to seem something like a `connect()` and a `query()` method.

Following this argument, **private** methods are "less important" and can be at the bottom of your class.