# Iteration inside a using or using inside an Iteration

Tags: c#, design-patterns, entity-framework

Is there a best practice for iterations inside of a "using"? which is better? and maybe a why?

"using" inside of an iteration...

```
foreach (var currentPerson in Persons)
{
    using (var db = new SolutionModel())
    {
        //TODO: run query
    }
}
```

or is it better to do an iteration inside of a "using"...

```
using (var db = new SolutionModel())
{
    foreach (var currentPerson in Persons)
    {        
        //TODO: run query
    }
}
```

FYI: coding in C#

Comment: You probably don't want to open a new connection for each person.  What you probably want is to open a connection, process each person on that connection, and then close the connection.  But your chosen strategy really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Would you please care at least about letting us know which programming language you are using for your code?

Comment: coding in C# using .NET and Entity Frameworks

Comment: Another option that may or may not suite your situation is to perform just a single large query across all persons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you know if you've written readable and easily maintainable code?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code)

Comment: The second one looks a lot quicker and cheaper but you should really try this on a large (database) set, time it and look at resource use.

Comment: so... I came across [this](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/Dec/21/Gotcha-Entity-Framework-gets-slow-in-long-Iteration-Loops) earlier today. Seems like sample 2 would be the norm but when it comes to Entity Framework its better to do sample 1. only way to truly find out is testing it on a large iteration of objects. I'm just not sure how large of an iteration I will come across in this specific solution.

Comment: @Hakubex: you missed the point. As David Arno told you, your two examples have a certain risk of not not behaving similar (for example, in when thinking about transactions and failures, and also when thinking about performance). So this is not a matter of "style" or "norm" or "best practice", it is a matter of correctness and required performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, a new `SolutionModel` will be created, `run query`will be called once and then `Dispose()` will be called on it, for every item in `Persons`.

In the second case, just one `SolutionModel` will be created and `run query` will be called multiple times on that one instance before it's disposed..

So there is no "best practice" at play here. *You* need to decide which is the correct action based on what you want to happen as `Persons` is enumerated.

Comment: You obviously shouldn't create `SolutionModel` for each and every person *if it is not necessary*.  However I agree completely that the person who decides this is the OP.