# Common way to name methods with same name as desired variable?

Tags: refactoring, naming, naming-standards

I frequently find myself pulling up helper methods in order to make my code better, but end up with duplicate method names. Is there a standard way to name such methods without getting duplicate names?

Example of code before:

```
function hello(suffix) {
  if (typeof suffix === 'string') {
    return `Hello ${suffix}`
  } else {
    return 'Invalid entry'
  }
}
```

Becomes:

```
function hello(suffix) {
  const isSuffixString = isSuffixString(suffix) // can't do in JavaScript
  if (isSuffixString) {
    return `Hello ${suffix}`
  } else {
    return 'Invalid entry'
  }
}
```

Of course this is contrived and isn't very useful, but it illustrates the point.

I could call the helper `getIsSuffixString`, for example, but it feels like too much.

I just find that the helper method name and the ensuing variable often should have the same name.

Comment: It really depends on how many of these you have in a given method or section of code, but I find myself trying to have the method name as some variant of "TryParse" (TryParseSuffix in the example case), then if I need to use the true/false beyond the initial check I would make the variable something like isValidSuffix. For the comment in the example "can't do in javascript", I forget what you can/can't do from that perspective, but are there any other limitations in what you would look for in an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,  in the shown case, it makes no sense to introduce an explaining variable since using the function directly is equally readable, so you could write:

```
function hello(suffix) {
  if (isSuffixString(suffix)) {
    return `Hello ${suffix}`
  } else {
    return 'Invalid entry'
  }
}
```

However, if you need the result of a function call more than once, it may be useful to store the value of a function call to avoid multiple calls, even if it does not add anything in readability. In a case-sensitive language, one could make use of the convention for beginning method names with an upper case letter, but local variables with a lower case letter:

```
const isSuffixString = IsSuffixString(suffix)
```

Unfortunately, there are lots of environments where the usual convention is to use lower case letters for both, functions and local variables. In those languages, I would recommend to use a more descriptive name for what the functions does, and a slightly more abbreviated name for local variables, like:

```
const isSuffixString = isTypeofSuffixEqualToString(suffix)
```

And of course, it would also work the other way round, but that's up to your personal taste. Use whatever [your peer reviewer tells you he/she understands best](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/141005/how-would-you-know-if-youve-written-readable-and-easily-maintainable-code).

Comment: Thanks, I think the latter example is probably the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a matter of personal tastes.

I have several verb prefixes that I use for functions. In your case I'd use **check**. For me, a function like `check...()` must always return true or false (or raise an exception), and must be idempotent.

So I would write,

```
const checkedIsSuffixString = checkIsSuffixString(suffix)
if (checkedIsSuffixString) {
    // suffix has been checked and is a string.
    // (This comment is clearly redundant)
    ...
}
```